# How to show Feed back message in sales force Standard page?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I want to show a  Feed back message in sales force Standard page on custom button click using visual force page on the basis of Apex class logic.Any one who can help me?For example if some thing successfully done then success message and if not error message should display on standard page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new method to handle your messages

```
private void displayFeedback(ApexPages.Severity msgType, String message) 
{
    ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(msgType, message);
    ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
}
```

Build your message you want to show..

```
displayFeedback(ApexPages.Severity.Error, String.valueOf(TripProfileHandlerServices.ERROR_SAVING_DATA + missingDataError));
```

Put this message in your VF page

```
<apex:pageMessages id="feedback" />
```

You will also have to `rerender='feedback"`  when you want show the message after an event

Answer (score 0):

If you put a [`<apex:messages />`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_messages.htm) in the page, you can use the [message class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_message.htm) to fill it up.